# How to prevent sending same data to different clients in REST api GET?

Tags: rest, distributed-system

I have 15 worker clients and one master connected through internet.  Job & data are been passed through REST api in json format. 
Jobs are not restricted to any particular client.  Any worker can query for the available job in regular interval(say 30 seconds), process it and will update the status.
In this scenario, how can I prevent same records been sent to different clients while GET request.

Followings are my solution approach to overcome this issue:

Take top 5 unprocessed records from the database and make it as SENT and expose via REST GET. 
But the problem is, it creates inconsistency.  Some times, the client doesn't got data due to network connectivity issue. But in server, it will be marked as SENT. So, no other clients can get that data. It will remain as SENT forever.

Get the list from server, and reply back the list of job IDs to Server as received.  But in-between this time gap, some other clients also getting same set of Jobs.

Answer (score 3):

You've stumbled upon a fundamental problem in distributed systems: *there is **no way** to know if the other side received your message.* You can certainly improve the situation with TCP and ack messages. But if you never get the ACK did the message never arrive, did it arrive but the recipient die before processesing, or did the recipient send he ACK and the ACK get dropped?

That means you need to design your system to handle receiving data more than once.

You offer two partial solutions; if you combine them, your solution starts to look like how SQS works. Mark the item as `pending_ack` with a timestamp. After client replies, it is marked `sent`. Any `pending_acks`s past a certain time period are eligible to be resent.

Pick your time period to allow for slow network and slow clients and it boils down to only sending duplicates when you really don't know if the client died or not.

Comment: Combining both is good option. I am wondering how I missed to think in that way. You rocks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reconsider the approach to blocking resources. REST architecture - by definition is not obliged to save information about client. Instead, you may want to consider optimistic concurrency control (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).